# How to display button name on another page when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to display the name of a button on another page when a button is clicked. For example:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"> <?php echo $sql->name; ?></a>
```

The **echo $sql->name** displays two buttons like. I want to make the names of the buttons appear on the next page. For instance, if a button is 'Maths' and another, 'English'. When I click on Maths, the next page should have Maths as a heading.
I'm avoiding manually doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: write the form code where you havce the two buttons

Comment: Pass the name to the next page via GET or HTTP header or something, and fetch this name in PHP and output the name to wherever you like.

Comment: @Passerby please can you illustrate with an example. I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    <a href="your_page.php?button=maths" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Maths</a>
<a href="your_page.php?button=english" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Maths</a>
```

on your_page.php you can easily get which button is pressed by the following command

```
$pressedButton = $_REQUEST['button'];
echo $pressedbutton;
```

Comment: Thanks but the code **<?php echo $sql->name; ?>** displays as many buttons from the database if it matches the query so I can't change the <a href=""> as you suggested. I have only one line of code which displays two buttons. Sorry if I'm not making myself clear.