# How to load information to another page when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

When I click a button, I'm trying to get the name of the button to display on the next page. So far, I've managed to display the button name in an alert box but not sure how to get it to appear on another page.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        alert("Text: " + $("#test").text());
    });
});
</script>
```

The code below gets modules that the logged in user is registered to and displays two buttons. I'm trying to display the button label(subject names) on another page rather than in the alert box. So when I click on a button, the label name appears on the next page.

```
$sql = DB::getInstance()->get('modules', array('username','=' ,$user->data()->username));
            if(!$sql->count()){
                echo 'No data';
            }else {
                foreach ($sql->results() as $sql){ ?>
                    <p><a href="try.php" class=" btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="test"> <?php echo $sql->name; ?></a></p>
```

Comment: The result of the button click is to navigate to another page entirely i.e. window.location = '...' on click?  It is a button tag or anchor?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to display button name on another page when button is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526417/how-to-display-button-name-on-another-page-when-button-is-clicked) . Why post the same question twice?

Comment: @phillip100 it's different. I figured out how to display button label. My question here is how to load it into another page.

Comment: Well... I see no difference between these questions - they're precisely the same to me. Voted to close.

Comment: @phillip100 should i delete the other question, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to navigate to another page on click, you can just modify your jquery event handler to this and pull it out of the query params on the next page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        window.location = "your_next_page.php?name=" + $("#test").text();
    });
});
```

on your other page.

```
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST['name'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the $sql->name to session data and use this another page

```
$sql = DB::getInstance()->get('modules', array('username','=' ,$user->data()->username));
            if(!$sql->count()){
                echo 'No data';
            }else {
                foreach ($sql->results() as $sql){ 
$_SESSION['name'] = $sql->name;?>
                    <p><a href="try.php" class=" btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" id="test"> <?php echo $sql->name; ?></a></p>
```

another_page.php

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```